# Bash formatting an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, text

I have something like this:

```
CC-20125634 -86 WPA
House -90 WPA2
HelloWorld -67 WPA2
```

and I would like to format it like this:

```
CC-20125634 -86 WPA
House       -90 WPA2
HelloWorld  -67 WPA2
```

How could I achive this?

Comment: Should the output in this case equal the input? If so, what is the sorting rule?

Comment: There is a utility called `sort` that may be useful.   `man sort` will explain how to sort alphabetically or numerically by a set of columns, how to define columns, etc.  Does `sort` solve your problem?  If not, why not?

Comment: You use the word "sort", but it looks like what you've actually changed is not the ordering but the padding? Also, your title and tag mention arrays, but it's not clear whether you mean that in that actual Bash sense. When you say that you "have something", do you mean that that's the contents of a text-file, or . . . ?

Comment: Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example, you appear to want columns formatted nicely.  If that is the case, you can used `column` to produce output like this:

```
$ column -t input.data
CC-20125634  -86  WPA
House        -90  WPA2
HelloWorld   -67  WPA2
```

Comment: things are so easy when you know what  screw to tight. Thanks a lot mate.